# Can't get 'mysql' gem to work after installing Yosemite

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I installed Yosemite last night and discovered that mysql had been de-installed in the process. I downloaded the .dmg file from the MySQL website, reinstalled it, started it up, no problem.

However, when ran 'rake db:migrate' to rebuild the database on the Sinatra project I'm working on, I got the following:

```
sh-3.2$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql/2.1/mysql_api
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/identry/Documents/ios/projects/GagnonPhoto/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I get the same error if I run irb and type: require 'mysql'.

Seems like the mysql install is missing something, but I'm not sure what. Any clues much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend installing mysql with homebrew.  There might be some dependencies you're missing by only running the .dmg.  `brew install mysql`

Comment: Sorry... just discovered this question has been answered before. The answer is to add 'export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' to .bash_profile.